# Converting python dataframe into dictionary and then into a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe called `users_df` that looks like this

| id | first_name | last_name | signup_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | Smith | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | Mark | Adams | 2021-03-02 |
| 3 | Mary | Rose | 2021-05-03 |

```
users_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'James', 'Smith', '2021-01-01'], [2, 'Mark', 'Adams', '2021-03-02'],[3, 'Mary', 'Rose', '2021-05-03']], columns=['id', 'first_name','last_name', 'signup_date'])
```

Which I am trying to convert into a dictionary first that looks like this:

```
user_dict = {
    "users": [
        {"id": 1, "user_fields": {"first_name": "James", "last_name": "Smith", "signup_date": "2021-01-01"}}, 
        {"id": 2, "user_fields": {"first_name": "Mark", "last_name": "Adams", "signup_date": "2021-03-02"}}, 
        {"id": 3, "user_fields": {"first_name": "Mary", "last_name": "Rose", "signup_date": "2021-05-03"}}
    ]
}
```

And then finally convert that into a string:

```
user_dict_string = '{"users": [{"id": 1, "user_fields": {"first_name": "James", "last_name": "Smith", "signup_date": "2021-01-01"}}, {"id": 2, "user_fields": {"first_name": "Mark", "last_name": "Adams", "signup_date": "2021-03-02"}}, {"id": 3, "user_fields": {"first_name": "Mary", "last_name": "Rose", "signup_date": "2021-05-03"}}]}'
```

The part where I am stuck is converting the dataframe into the dictionary while keeping the "id" part (see the example below when I do `to_dict('index')`) and then adding the `"users"` list and the nested `"user_fields"` parts.

All I could find is using this:

```
user_dict = user_list.to_dict('index')
```

But the results look like this which is not what I am after

```
{1: {'first_name': 'James', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'signup_date': '2021-01-01'}, 2: {'first_name': 'Mark', 'last_name': 'Adams', 'signup_date': '2021-03-02'}, 3: {'first_name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Rose', 'signup_date': '2021-05-03'}}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use dict comprehension to create the records in the desired format

```
{'users': [{'id': d.pop('id'), 'user_fields': d} for d in users_df.to_dict('r')]}
```

---

```
{'users': [{'id': 1,
            'user_fields': {'first_name': 'James',
                            'last_name': 'Smith',
                            'signup_date': '2021-01-01'}},
           {'id': 2,
            'user_fields': {'first_name': 'Mark',
                            'last_name': 'Adams',
                            'signup_date': '2021-03-02'}},
           {'id': 3,
            'user_fields': {'first_name': 'Mary',
                            'last_name': 'Rose',
                            'signup_date': '2021-05-03'}}]}
```

Comment: that's look pretty neat

Answer (score 1):

You could use a comprehension to build the expected struct from

```
users_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'James', 'Smith', '2021-01-01'],
                         [2, 'Mark', 'Adams', '2021-03-02'],
                         [3, 'Mary', 'Rose', '2021-05-03']],
                        columns=['id', 'first_name','last_name', 'signup_date'])
```

You have already find that:

```
users_df.set_index('id').to_dict('index')
```

gives:

```
{1: {'first_name': 'James', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'signup_date': '2021-01-01'},
 2: {'first_name': 'Mark', 'last_name': 'Adams', 'signup_date': '2021-03-02'},
 3: {'first_name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Rose', 'signup_date': '2021-05-03'}}
```

Just add one step:

```
user_dict = {'users': [{'id': k, 'user_fields': v}
               for k, v in users_df.set_index('id').to_dict('index')
               .items()]}
```

to get:

```
{'users': [{'id': 1,
            'user_fields': {'first_name': 'James',
                            'last_name': 'Smith',
                            'signup_date': '2021-01-01'}},
           {'id': 2,
            'user_fields': {'first_name': 'Mark',
                            'last_name': 'Adams',
                            'signup_date': '2021-03-02'}},
           {'id': 3,
            'user_fields': {'first_name': 'Mary',
                            'last_name': 'Rose',
                            'signup_date': '2021-05-03'}}]}
```

And a simple `json.dumps` will convert it to a string...